# Django 1.10 Form doesn't store data to DB

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I feel very stupid and confused, tackling this issue for so long.
It works completely fine, displays survey fine, however it does not store(save) submited form to my database. I have seen tons of questions/solutions, however none of them helped me.

Here are my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
#from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField,
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from django.forms import ModelForm
# Create your models here.

    class user_prefs(models.Model):
            cuisine_choice = (
                ('1', 'Italian'),
                ('2', 'American'),
                ('3', 'Japanese'),
                ('4', 'French'),
                ('5', 'Mexican'),
                ('6', 'Chinese'),
                ('7', 'Indian'),
                ('8', 'Middle Eastern')
            )
            lunch_pref = (
                ('1', 'Coffeehouse'),
                ('2', 'Cafe'),
                ('3', 'Restaurant'),
                ('4', 'Fast Food'),
                ('5', 'Takeaway'),
                ('6', 'Stake House')
            )
            dinner_pref = (
                ('1', 'Restaurant'),
                ('2', 'Takeaway'),
                ('3', 'Delivery'),
                ('4', 'Fast food'),
                ('5', 'Coffeehouse'),
                ('6', 'Cafe'),
                ('7', 'Cooking at home')
            )
            sunday = (
                ('1', 'Cultural activities(Museums, Galleries, Exhibitions etc.)'),
                ('2', 'Sport activities'),
                ('3', 'Attending sport events'),
                ('4', 'Music events'),
                ('5', 'Hiking'),
                ('6', 'Going to park')
            )
            friday = (
                ('1', 'Bar'),
                ('2', 'Nightclub'),
                ('3', 'Karaoke'),
                ('4', 'Netflix & chill'),
                ('5', 'Videogames'),
                ('6', 'Cinema'),
                ('7', 'Theater'),
                ('8', 'Restaurant')
            )
            userID = models.ForeignKey(User) #related_name='User', null=True
            Cuisine = models.IntegerField(choices=cuisine_choice)
            Cuisine1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
            LunchPref = models.IntegerField(choices=lunch_pref)
            DinnerPref = models.IntegerField(choices=dinner_pref)
            Sunday = models.IntegerField(choices=sunday)
            Friday = models.IntegerField(choices=friday)
```

Seems fine to me so far.

here is ModelForm(forms.py)

```
class user_prefsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user_prefs
        fields = ['Cuisine', 'Cuisine1', 'LunchPref', 'DinnerPref', 'Sunday', 'Friday']


form = user_prefsForm()
```

here is views.py

```
def display1(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    #form = user_prefsForm(request.POST)
def display(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_prefsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.userID = request.user
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = user_prefsForm()
        return render(request, 'display.html', {'form': form})
```

template

```
Please state your preferences below
 <form action='/' method="POST" >
     {% csrf_token %}
     <p>What is you favourite cuisine?</p>
    {{ form.Cuisine }}
    <p>If not listed above or you want to add more to that, coud you please tell us? </p>
    {{ form.Cuisine1 }}
    <p>What would be your lunch preference ?</p>
    {{ form.LunchPref }}
    <p>What would be your Dinner preference ?</p>
    {{ form.DinnerPref }}
    <p>What would you do on your Friday free time ?</p>
    {{ form.Sunday }}
    <p>What would you do on Sunday?</p>
    {{ form.Friday }}
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    {% endif %}
 </html>
```

Just in case urls.py(tho i dont think there would be any issues, however):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^letusknow/', display, name='display'),
    url(r'^letusknow/', display1, name='display1'),
    ]
```

Initially I had models.CharField in my models, that didnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are redirecting to the home page regardless of whether the form is valid or not.

```
def display(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_prefsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.userID = request.user
            form.save()
            # note indentation change here.
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = user_prefsForm()
    # note identation change here.
    return render(request, 'display.html', {'form': form})
```

Additionally in your template you are not rendering the fields correctly, some of the errors in the form will never be displayed. Please refer to this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Unless you fix the template the user will never know that he filled the form incorrectly.

Comment: so if I do 
else:
return HttpResponseRedirect('page.html') it would work ?

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: I have shown you the correct form, please use it. And change your template

Comment: oh i see , the indentation .. gonna try it now!

Comment: but that in itself wont fix it, you have to fix the template too

Comment: well, the form could not possibly filled incorrectly, it outputs multiple choice w/ 1 possible selection and only 1 field for characters w/ 30 length, but for sure going to check it out right now. Going to read it through and see, thanks a lot though !

Comment: one never makes assumptions about forms.

Comment: With a change back to CharField in models.py I managed to finally do this hahaha. Thanks a lot !